# Duplicate folders after Thunderbird upgrade in Debian 12

Tags: thunderbird

Today I upgraded Debian stable from 12.1 to 12.2 which included an update of the email client Thunderbird to version 115.3.1 (64-bit). With the new version I have several folders which have been duplicated: Drafts, Sent Mail/Sent, Spam/Junk and Trash. I have tried to remove the account from Thunderbird and adding it again (with all settings on default) but the problem persists. Any clues?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the account in the folder pane (in this case fusionfile@gmail.com) and select *Subscribe* in the popup menu. Then uncheck the folders that you don't want to see in Thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

The *upgrade process* to that version of Thunderbird does have a few bugs, including resurrecting old accounts and, in this case creating default folders, or resurrecting  previously renamed or deleted folders. Note that the folders are distinct: "Sent **Mail**" vs. *Sent*, and "**>** Trash" vs. "Trash" (one has subfolders).

- Look inside the folders. Likely one of each pair has no files or subfolders; delete that folder. (On my PC, "Sent Mail" is valid, and "Trash" has no right angle bracket).
- Note that Gmail uses the term "Spam", but T'bird may create a default "Junk" folder, which can be removed.
- If unsure, send some email to "Trash" by deleting it; the trash folder with the deleted message should be kept.
- If the folder is a Gmail default, no problem: you won't be able to delete it.

Comment: Unsubscribing from the duplicate folders seems to be the proper solution.